# iOS application updates

Tags: ios, objective-c, app-store

I want to update the iOS app **without submitting the new version** to app store and **without rejecting the previous binary**.

Please let know the reason **why it is not allowed**.

Comment: "I want to update the iOS app without submitting the new version" - what this mean? If there are no change in new binary then why u r "updating" it? and if there are changes then why u r hesitating to upload it as new version?

Comment: "Not allowed" - are you asking about some appstore policy? Shouldn't you ask Apple?

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible,

If you want to update you must submit your new binary to apple store.

Because apple want apps must be quality control.

Answer (score 0):

Because Apple do not want to see junk in appstore. They need to review Your build at first to be shure that all OK.

Comment: Is there any links from Apple mentioning this.
I need to update with reference.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/support/appstore/app-review/